# Bad users are not punished enough!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, users, behavior

A user has asked 25 questions and accepted no answers. Clearly they have a 0% accept and few medals. However, simply from the badge it is not possible to know if they are a bad users or a new user (you have to visit their page to know the number of questions they have asked).

I suggest the accepted answer bit of the tag should read 0/25 which clearly shows the lack of the individual. For good users this may get unwieldy (eg 345/350) so perhaps after a certain threshold the badge should revert to percentages.

I had not noticed the mouse-over behaviour, so perhaps some hint that exists for discoverability... or am I just SO fail?

Comment: This is a dupe of ...... something asked before.

Comment: why should someone really care about this information.  In some cases it is from a user who is not engaged - in other cases the person may have many questions in a narrow topic that there is no real good help.

Comment: @tim: I believe the percentage is only calculated for non-CW questions for which there is at least one upvoted answer. So a question in narrow topic that gets no good answers does not harm the accept rate.

Comment: 25 questions with no accepted answers isn't terrible. It's a bad start, but it's not unrecoverable.

Comment: I'd still like to see "brown badges" given out for bad behaviour (that could be unearned through redemption), as also proposed elsewhere. e.g 10 posts with value below zero, days in the penalty box, numbers of flagged posts etc...

Comment: I would collect them ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I've written a Greasemonkey script to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16643/add-the-number-of-questions-used-in-the-acceptance-rate-criteria-to-the-display/16876#16876).

Answer (score 18):

How do you define bad user? Their accept rate shows (to an extent) their engagement in the site, but isn't everything. I'm not sure that the questions they've asked are that well-phrased or generally useful, but no amount of statistics are going to tell you that.

Use the accept-rate as a hint of whether you're likely to get much feedback from the questioner, but not as a guide to whether the user is "good" or "bad".

Answer (score 14):

If you hover over the "accept rate", a tooltip will pop up, providing the raw numbers for the percentage.

Answer (score 11):

The ONLY two penalties for not accepting an answer is not receiving the 2 points rep for selecting an answer, and having a low accepted answer rate (which may have secondary consequences).

That's it, and those are the only penalties there should be.

As you can see by the questions there are many users who had answers voted up by the community, so the questions did generate good rep for those who took the time to answer them.

There is no reason to punish those users that don't fully engage with the site - that they are engaging at all is a good thing, overall, and we shouldn't exclude or further punish them.

Let them decide how deeply to involve themselves.

Answer (score 4):

This has already been addressed. Hover over the percentage and you can see the number of accepted answers and number of eligible questions.

Answer (score 4):

Well if you hover your mouse over the accept rate you'll see a tooltip that goes:

> this user has accepted an answer for 0 of 16 eligible questions

While it's not "in your face" the information is there. So if you see a low accept rate get the tooltip up and you can make your decision.