# "New answers have been posted" notification although the only answer is mine

Tags: bug, status-deferred, answers, notifications

This might be anywhere from "by-design" to a non-issue, but I thought I'd mention it:

When I posted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35238/up-down-vote-actual-users/35239#35239) (i.e. after I clicked "Post Your Answer"), the "New answers have been posted. Load new answers" notification briefly appeared before the page was reloaded. Since, as random confirmed, there where no other answers on that question, it must have been my own answer that triggered the notification.

<sub>Side note: I was tempted to title this post ["The quicker-than-his-own-shadow problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Luke)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a rare race condition between the timing of the JavaScript background AJAX check for new answers and the save..

also, it's even rarer to answer your own question on top of that.

Comment: I was fooled by the title as well, but this was not a case of answering ones own question. It was about posting the one and only answer to someone else's question, and then very briefly seeing the message "New answers have been posted". (I've never seen that.)

Comment: I have changed the title to hopefully clarify

Comment: FWIW It seems to be fairly common on StackExchange sites. I've seen it happen on 3 or 4. I post an answer to *someone else's* question, as the answer is being submitted the alert pops up, then when the resultant page is displayed mine is the only answer.

Comment: I've seen this twice over a period of ten minutes today.

Comment: @sharp we just did several deploys, I wonder if that is related?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I guess it is. I never encountered this behavior earlier and I saw it twice in ten minutes today.

Answer (score 0):

Ya even I have observed similar things ..

Usually because the notification response is a bit slower .. It takes few minutes (not sure about the number) or more to notify ..
By the time .. We will be having checked the response manually ..

One more possibility is that .. when I check the response after seeing the notification and come BACK to the same page (by pressing the BACK button in browser) then also the same notification does alert me ..

I posted it just for casual discussion ..

Comment: You're talking about the little envelope next to your username, right? That's not what I mean. I'm talking about the notification bar that comes up when you're writing on an answer while someone else has posted an answer on the same question in the meantime.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/latency-of-the-red-envelope

Comment: oh ok .. slight misunderstanding .. :-P